# Only closed under finite intersection and union ... how can we still topologize?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, O)$ be a countable set together with a countable collection of subsets that are closed under finite intersection and union and contain all of $X$ as well as the empty set. How can we make this into a topological space? This data is very nearly a topological space, but not quite.

Since the set of subsets of this data is not closed under infinite intersection or union is there a canonical method (or multiple methods) available to topologize this data (via closed or open sets) so that we can use tools from topology?

Comment: You can generate a topology by this collection, taking all possibles unions of sets of your collection, although this will (possibly) get a much larger collection. 

This will indeed be the smallest topology with the sets of the collection being the open sets.

Comment: @FelipeMonteiro https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evenly_spaced_integer_topology like this? Can I do it the complementary way via intersection?

Comment: @Ringminustwo that will produce the smallest topology in which your sets are *closed*

Comment: Yeah, that's right.

Comment: @jkabrg would it be a base for that topology?

Comment: base for the closed sets

Answer (score 3):

Your collection $O$ does form a base for a topology (having $X$ in it and closed under finite intersections implies this). So for me the natural way would be just to take $O$ as a base for the topology and declare $U$ to be open iff for every $x \in U$ there is some $O_x \in O$ with $O_x \subseteq U$, or equivalently take the set of all unions of subfamilies of $O$.

Countability of sets $O$ and/or $X$ are irrelevant in this, I think.

You could also take $O$ to be a base for the closed sets, i.e. define closed sets to be all intersections of subfamilies of $O$, though this is less usual. It will depend on your application which is more natural.

Comment: Can I declare U closed iff for every x in U there is some Ox in O with U contained in or equal to Ox, equivalently the set of all intersections of subfamilies of O? The reason for this is because O contains all the singletons so If I do it in your way in my case I necessarily get the discrete space.

Comment: @RingRing singletons in $O$ will give the discrete topology. You can Aldo dually use it as a base for the closed sets and take the set of all intersections of subfamilies of $O$ as the closed sets of a topology.